# bash alias function for curl

Tags: bash, function, curl, alias

I want to setup a bash alias for curl so I only need to pass the file and server url.

I have tried variations of

```
alias upload='function _upload(){ curl -F 'file=@"$1"' "$2"; };_upload'
```

without success

I also need to some basic checking when i execute the alias i.e if i only do

```
upload file.txt
```

it should return "destination server missing" as I haven't entered the server url. Same should be done if the filename is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use aliases for anything complicated. Stick to functions.

```
upload() {
    [[ "$1" ]] || { echo "Error: Missing file" >&2; return 1; }
    [[ "$2" ]] || { echo "Error: Missing url"  >&2; return 1; }
    curl -F "file=@$1" "$2"
}
```

Comment: I would shorten the first two lines using the `:?` parameter expansion operator: `: ${1:?Error: Missing file}`.